# Android views and lines distort when zooming

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-viewgroup

I have a FrameLayout on which I am drawing some lines (on the canvas via the onDraw method) and some rectangular objects (FrameLayouts which are added to the parent FrameLayout via the addView method). The basic idea is that the lines represent a map of roads/ railway lines etc and the objects represent vehicles. The issue I am having is that when I zoom the parent FrameLayout the map lines and the borders of the vehicles sometimes become thicker, thinner or disappear completely. It seems to be linked to the zoom factor. I've tried setting the anti alias flag for the lines and making them thicker but it still happens. I've also tried making the borders (background shape drawable with stroke) of the vehicles thicker and using a nested filled view with padding/margins rather than using a background drawable but that doesn't make any difference either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Code, code. Give us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to vary the thickness of the lines and any dimension and Text size according to the zoom factor